# How to open a context menu for mudblazor treeview

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am trying to open a context menu on right click on node of treeview, how this can be done?
I did not find anything in mudblazor documentation

Comment: https://github.com/stavroskasidis/BlazorContextMenu Try this Package to enable Conext Menu on various components.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <MudMenu PositionAtCursor="true" ActivationEvent="@MouseEvent.RightClick">
            <ActivatorContent>
                <MudTreeView T="ItemResponse"
                             Color="Color.Primary"
                             Items="@Items.ToHashSet()"
                             @bind-ActivatedValue="SelectedItem"
                             Hover=true>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <MudTreeViewItem Items="@context.Items.ToHashSet()"
                                         @bindExpanded="@context.IsExpanded"
                                         Value="@context"
                                         Text="@context.DisplayMember"
                                         Icon="@context.Icon"
                                         EndText="@context.Value"
                                         EndTextTypo="@Typo.body1">
                        </MudTreeViewItem>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </MudTreeView>
            </ActivatorContent>
            <ChildContent>
                    <MudMenuItem>Delete</MudMenuItem>
                    <MudMenuItem>Edit</MudMenuItem>
            </ChildContent>
        </MudMenu>
```